# How do I capture a changed element's id and then use that to manipulate the browser object?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to build an editing interface for podcast episodes.

Each podcast has many chapters, each of which has an image associated with it.

I would like to enable my users to be able to click a "replace image" button to dynamically swap out the existing image and replace it with a new upload.

I have successfully built a solution based on this approach - http://jsfiddle.net/vbrHA/

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#podcast-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        if( $('#imgInp').val()!=""){

            $('#remove').show();
            $('#podcast-image').show('slow');
      }
        else{ $('#remove').hide();$('#podcast-image').hide('slow');}
        readURL(this);
    });
    $('#remove').click(function(){
          $('#imgInp').val('');
          $(this).hide();
          $('#podcast-image').hide('slow');
 $('#podcast-image').attr('src','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/No_pub.svg/150px-No_pub.svg.png');
});
```

- to enable users to change one image, but I am unsure how I now re-write this to handle multiple image ids so that I don't have to duplicate the code multiple times.

Each chapter image has a unique id, so I envisage a button next to each image that will pass that id to the jquery code above and then swap the correct image in the browser... but beyond the theory I am now stuck.

Can anyone guide me how to proceed please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can use `data` attributes to associate the remove button and the file field to the correspondent image, and to each other. You'll get something like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='button' value="remove" id='imgInp_remove' data-image='imgInp_image' data-file='imgInp_file' class='hide remove'/>
    <input type='file' data-image='imgInp_image' data-remove='imgInp_remove' class="file" id="imgInp_file" /><br>
    <img id="imgInp_image" class="image" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

Then, you need to "capture" the data attributes in your code. Since the events will be attached to several images and buttons, you'll have to use classes to attach the events instead of IDs. You'll get something like this:

```
$('.image').hide();
$('.remove').hide();  
function readURL(input, $image) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $image.attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$(".file").change(function(){
    var $file = $(this);
    var $image = $('#' + $file.data('image'));
    var $remove = $('#' + $file.data('remove'));
    if ($file.val()!=""){
        $remove.show();
        $image.show('slow');
    }
    else{ 
        $remove.hide();
        $image.hide('slow');
    }
    readURL(this, $image);
});


$('.remove').click(function(){
    var $remove = $(this);
    var $image = $('#' + $remove.data('image'));
    var $file = $('#' + $image.data('file'));
    $file.val('');
    $remove.hide();
    $image.hide('slow');  
    $image.attr('src','http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/No_pub.svg/150px-No_pub.svg.png');
});
```

And that's basically it. When you want to add another image, simply replace the image, file and button IDs and their correspondent `data` attributes. You won't have to modify your javascript at all.

Comment: Thank you, both, very much for helping me. 

Can you clarify this for me:

"Since the events will be attached to several images and buttons, you'll have to use classes to attach the events instead of IDs."

I don't understand the reference to ids - these are unique so why can I not use those?

Comment: Yes, the IDs are unique, but class names can be used for several elements. So, if you do, for example `$('#my_id').click(...)`, that'll bind the click event to the one element with the `my_id` id. But if you do `$('.my_class').click(...)`, that'll bind the click event to every single element that has the class `my_class`.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still really struggling with this. I tried to use your example above as a starting point, but it does not work; without a working starting point it's really hard for me to work out what's wrong...

Comment: I just realized I didn't answer this comment. When you attach events to elements, if you use the ID to do this, like so: `$('#my_id').click(...)`, since the ID is unique for an element, that event will be attached to one, and only one, element. But if you use a class name, like so: `$('.my_class').click(...)`, that event will be attached to every element with the `.my_class` class. The keyword `this` inside the event handler will refer to the particular element that triggered the event. Also, I tested my example in jsfiddle and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`data-*`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) attribute for the buttons. I imagine the html would look something like: `<input type='button' class="btn-image-change" data-imgId="[imageId]"/>`

In the JS, you could do something like:

```
$('input.btn-image-change').click(function(){
    var imgId = $(this).data("imgId");
    //call to your function that handles the image change
}
```